# Errors on catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin-make, gradle, message-generation, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

i'm trying to built some package in catkin_ws but the catkin_make gives me the following errors:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'nao_writing_android_nodes'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec:1.3.0.
> Required by:
> :nao_writing_android_nodes:unspecified > org.ros.rosjava_messages:trajectory_msgs:1.10.6 > org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:message_generation:0.3.0
> Could not find org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io:1.4.0.
> Required by:
> :nao_writing_android_nodes:unspecified > org.ros.rosjava_messages:trajectory_msgs:1.10.6 > org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:message_generation:0.3.0
> Could not find org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang:2.4.0.
> Required by:
> :nao_writing_android_nodes:unspecified > org.ros.rosjava_messages:trajectory_msgs:1.10.6 > org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:message_generation:0.3.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  make[2]: *** [nao_writing/nao_writing_android_nodes/CMakeFiles/gradle-nao_writing_android_nodes] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [nao_writing/nao_writing_android_nodes/CMakeFiles/gradle-nao_writing_android_nodes.dir/all] Error 2
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  Invoking "make -j1" failed

What can i do to fix them??

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258785/errors-on-catkin_make/) by [chri_io](https://answers.ros.org/users/29960/chri_io/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

did you try to resolve your dependencies? The command

```
rosdep install --from-paths ~/your-workspace/src --ignore-src
```

will try to resolve the dependencies of your packages. Then try again with

```
catkin_make
```

I hope that it will work for you.

---

Originally posted by [FLYINGKNIGHT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28071/flyingknight/) with karma: 36 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chri_io](https://answers.ros.org/users/29960/chri_io/) on 2017-04-09**:
Hello.

thank you for your answer. I get the following error:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: ros_markers: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [OpenCV]

What is the problem now?

thank you

**Comment by [FLYINGKNIGHT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28071/flyingknight/) on 2017-04-11**:
It seems like the package ros_markers does not provide the 'rosdep keys'. So rosdep can't resolve the dependencies for this package. Plz take a look at the rosdep command reference http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/commands.html. You could try to exclude the package from rosdep.